# I can't load video file from local server in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, nsurl, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm working with iOS using Swift.
I want to load a video file using AVPlayer in Swift.
I was able to load an image and a text file from the local server. But I couldn't load a video file. This is the code that I'm using.

```
let movieUrl = NSURL(string: "http://akjfsjf/ajdfl/ajkf/car.mp4")
let player = AVPlayer(URL: movieUrl!)
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

playerController.player = player
self.addChildViewController(playerController)
self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

player.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with following `URL` and `function`

```
func playvideo (){

        let movieUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4")
        let player = AVPlayer(URL: movieUrl!)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player
        player.play()
        self.addChildViewController(playerController)
        self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
        playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
    }
```

Also from your `code` i found you are using `http` rather than `https` so you need to add following `property` in `plist` file.

[image]

Comment: thank you for anwser! actually i already added property that you mentioned.. it is not working. when i wrote my url on crome, i can see the video. but when i wrote it on safari.... it was not working... then.. the local server has problem?? i don't know what problem is....

Comment: did you tried with `url` which i have added in my `answer`.?

Comment: @ Abhishek Sharma yes your url work. but your url is public url. isn't it? my case is private server, my own server url doesn't work. what is different between my url width yours?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? @shin

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {

var playerVC : AVPlayerViewController!
var playerItem : AVPlayerItem!
var player : AVPlayer!
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

            let url = NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: "your file path")

            self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: url!)
            self.player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: self.playerItem)
            self.playerVC = AVPlayerViewController.init();
            self.playerVC.player = self.player;
            self.player.currentItem!.playbackLikelyToKeepUp

            self.presentViewController(self.playerVC, animated: true) { () -> Void in
                self.playerVC.player?.play()
       }

    }
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: did you check that your code work or not? when I compiled your code, it didn't work. plz check your code and modify your code... thank you

Comment: I modified your code and compiled.. but unfortunately it didn't work... even though I use "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4", your code didn't work